# Change the ASCII of a typed character

Tags: c++, keyboard, ascii, keylogger

Im looking to make a program that mixes up all the keyboard letters/ASCII values. Sort of like the software version of taking off the keyboard letters and moving them around... Is there any way to do this? Right now, Im using an infinite while loop with a GetAsyncKeyState() inside to get any typed letters, but I dont know how to take that information and change it and put it back into system... Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like someone is trying to write some nasty program?

For Windows: The basic idea would be catching window messages (WM_KEYDOWN and WM_KEYUP) and change the key values/ids before passing them.

Depending on your version, this will require your code to run with administrator privileges.

I don't have any experience for other systems regarding this, but the basic idea would most likely be the same.

Comment: Well, my friend and I have been playing little pranks on eachother for like a week now. I just got hit with a water bucket that was on the door frame, and Im looking for ways to get him back :P

Comment: And also, do you have any code examples I could use? Ive actually never used C++ before. Im a java person, but seeing as java is constrained to more of a "local" thing (...Its limited to being in its little window, it cant go out and do other things on the system), it doesnt really work with that I want to do.

Comment: Think this one should work (it's like a minimal example): http://developer-resource.blogspot.de/2008/07/setwindowshookex-example.html (Didn't test it.) Inside `wireKeyboardProc` you'd have to check the vkCode passed and change it accordingly instead of writing to some file.

Comment: Thank you!! I can figure out how to randomly assign a new ASCII value, but how would I put the new value back into the system?

Comment: You have to pass the event data through `CallNextHookEx()` to other handlers (which is then sent to the active window/program). If you drop it (and don't send anything), other windows and stuff won't notice the key hit (this is usually intended for global shortcuts). Just as a reminder: Wouldn't do such nasty things in corp environments with people you wouldn't consider your buddies, as that's essentially "sabotage". :) No guarantee you're able to forge the event, but from my understanding this should be possible that way.